# Side menu bar with jonkykong cocoapod problem

Tags: swift, cocoapods, side-menu

I having a problem with my project. I followed code-less strotyboard implementation. My menubar isn't show correctly as you can see my pictures below. I also read a example of yours but I could not find solution. Is anyone using tjis cocoapod help me please. I stuck for this for long

[My storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7tOM.png)

[My results in simulator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwLT9.png)

Answer (score 0):

So i have e few questions since i can't really tell what's going on in the storyboard.
Is the "Page one View Controller" embedded in a "Navigation controller"?

I have noticed that the style of the CELL. needs to be Basic.
It is "Custom" from the beginning.

Change that if you haven't.

Comment: Yes, PageOneViewController is embedded. How can I make it custom from the beginning.

Comment: What you do is go to your .storyboard. Press the cell and go to "attribute" menu. Then press "Basic" istead of custom in the upper field.